# Install ubuntu 14.04 using pen drive

Tags: 14.04, 10.04, system-installation

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 ! i want to to install Ubuntu 14.04. But i don't have Ubuntu CD.

I know we can use flash drive to install Ubuntu 14.04 But don't know how. (I have seen by brother doing that, i have asked him how to do it but reply was find it out yourself.)

So please anyone can give me step wise instruction how to use simple flash drive to install ubuntu 14.04

Comment: mount the iso image into your pendrive and restart your pc then follow the same steps as you would do when you are installing it via a live cd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd use a small program called Unetbootin, it allows you to install any OS from a pendrive. Go here (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and download the Linux version or instead you can use the terminal to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

Next, you need to plug your pendrive and download Ubuntu from the Ubuntu website then save the file on a folder or on the desktok.

Then you run Unetbootin (it might ask you to run it as sudo, just enter your password), select the second option and browse to your ISO file and press OK. If your pen drive has enough space this should work, I use an 8GB pen drive.

Finally you restart your computer and go to the BIOS and select external media boot as the first one and install Ubuntu.

Comment: You need at least 4.5 GB free to install ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

As *agha rehan abbas* suggested you, first of all you have to download the Ubuntu installation image file (the .iso file).

Insert your USB flash drive in such a way that it auto-mount it. Open the Startup Disk Creator utility. You will probably find it in the menu: ***System --> Administration --> Startup Disk Creator***. Within this utility, select the .iso file you downloaded (you can look for it by clicking the button "Other") and your USB flash drive partition. Click first at the "Erase Disk" button and then at the "Make Startup Disk" button.

Now you have to access the BIOS setup of your computer and configure it to boot from USB flash drive. Boot from your pendrive and install Ubuntu as usual.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this can help you friend: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick.

Comment: @juan You should give little descriptive answer, but it was useful